# Delete an Alfresco query result

Tags: alfresco

I have an Alfresco (v4) result that throws an exception because some extra properties are unknown.
I can't get directly the document with the API (404 Not found)
But this document is in the ItemIterable when I do a query , calculating the number of results and iterating on the results the exception is thrown.
How to delete this document :
`<cmis:propertyId displayName="Alfresco Node Ref" localName="nodeRef" propertyDefinitionId="alfcmis:nodeRef" queryName="alfcmis:nodeRef"> <cmis:value>workspace://version2Store/abd4733b-e80c-4566-b649-d06367050696</cmis:value> /cmis:propertyId>`

Thanks for your help.

API: /alfresco/api/-default-/public/cmis/versions/1.1/atom/query => throws an Exception
API: /api/-default-/public/cmis/versions/1.1/atom/id => 404

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a solr index not being in sync with your repository.
Try to find the node using the node browser by browsing the expected parent folder. If the node does not exist, the index still stores the node's reference for any reason.
If possible a full reindex would be the easiest fix. If this is not possible (because the time for a reindex would take to long) you could still PURGE single nodes in the solr index. But since a orphaned node in the index should not happen, a full reindex would fix any other index issue you may have not seen yet.

How to do either one or the other s. [Solr monitoring and troubleshooting](https://docs.alfresco.com/content-services/5.2/admin/search/#solr-monitoring-and-troubleshooting)

Comment: Reindexation solved the issue, thank you very much.